# How can I determine which transactions have failed using a web3.js call

Tags: web3js, returndata

I am attempting to call transactions that execute methods on a contract in order to collect specific data. I am currently using `web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)` in order to view the transaction information.

I correctly receive a return value, however, I cannot see any data that helps me determine if this was a failed transaction. I want to be able to detect failed transactions so that I exclude failed transactions from my data.

When I called:

`web3.eth.getTransaction('0xb818a71e2d8bc6b661f463fbf96c91ecbf60610042b39da7e8806b2e0b5c2575', (e,r) => {tx = r})`

I received this return value:

```
{ blockHash:
   '0xfcce6583cfede31bd59b53ac4b562b391a0c1f1b8539f4961ded1418be50d241',
  blockNumber: 2856676,
  from: '0x852bCCfd7446D236C353C804881048124F2a32B1',
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: '25000000000',
  hash:
   '0xb818a71e2d8bc6b661f463fbf96c91ecbf60610042b39da7e8806b2e0b5c2575',
  input: '0x',
  nonce: 3,
  r:
   '0x60b4dcc69230b1a69775ad20d0c105dfbfc52c953031deb1dbeab8a726ece2d6',
  s:
   '0x2cbd567f6fcac3c5284f8b531e302ee8f037a695029164f1bc68bf1218e8361',
  to: '0x0F0F0fc0530007361933EaB5DB97d09aCDD6C1c8',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: '0x2d',
  value: '32000000000000000000' }
```

Is there anything in there that can tell me if the tx failed?

Comment: The function `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` should give you a transaction status. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the status with `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt()`.

Running that command with your tx hash will produce the following:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xb818a71e2d8bc6b661f463fbf96c91ecbf60610042b39da7e8806b2e0b5c2575')

> { blockHash:
   '0xfcce6583cfede31bd59b53ac4b562b391a0c1f1b8539f4961ded1418be50d241',
  blockNumber: 2856676,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  from: '0x852bccfd7446d236c353c804881048124f2a32b1',
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom:
   '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  status: false,
  to: '0x0f0f0fc0530007361933eab5db97d09acdd6c1c8',
  transactionHash:
   '0xb818a71e2d8bc6b661f463fbf96c91ecbf60610042b39da7e8806b2e0b5c2575',
  transactionIndex: 0 }
```

You can see that the `status` flag is set to `false`, which indicates that the transaction failed.

As a note, this was added in the Byzantium hard fork.